# Excel AddIn Event: How to display a dialog asking the user whether the workbook should be saved?

Tags: excel, vsto, office-interop, office-addins

Before the user is allowed to save an Excel workbook that is "invalid", I would like to inform them that they have managed to damage it and give them the opportunity to abandon all modifications.

By pressing a few times the [TAB] key, I was able to generate most of the code below:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace WithBeforeSave
{
  public partial class ThisAddIn
  {
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Application.WorkbookBeforeSave += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeSaveEventHandler(Application_WorkbookBeforeSave);
    }

    void Application_WorkbookBeforeSave(Excel.Workbook Wb, bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("How do I put the proper dialog here?");
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

Therefore, all I need is the C# equivalent to this:

[This example prompts the user for a yes or no response before saving the workbook.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-workbookbeforesave-event-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

TIA

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace WithBeforeSave
{
  public partial class ThisAddIn
  {
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Application.WorkbookBeforeSave += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeSaveEventHandler(Application_WorkbookBeforeSave);
    }

    void Application_WorkbookBeforeSave(Excel.Workbook Wb, bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        if (DialogResult.No == MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to save the DEFECTIVE, INVALID workbook?", "Example", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
        {
            Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Save is canceled.");
        }
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

That's it. I found the answer here:

[This example prompts the user for a yes or no response before saving any workbook.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbookbase.beforesave.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)